wsl fails to obtain permissions except root to access a newly prepared drive
I have purchased a NVMe SSD and installed it onto my desktop. I performed disk initialization and formatting as usual. But when I try to access the disk from wsl, a permission issue occurred.

my new drive is volumed as u. When I launch wsl from a folder in it, it is denied. Unless I have to sudo su, then it will let me access it.
I have attempted to chmod and chown for the whole drive. It took a long time, but the recycle disk contents cannot be changed. I am still unable to access any contents in U from wsl directly.
How to fix this issue?
